# Set all keys of an object to false or true including nested objects

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to set all the keys to either false or true based on an event.

```js
const odba = {
  "all": false,
  "allA": false,
  "allB": false,
  "allC": {
    "allD": false,
    "allE": { "allF": true },
  }
}

Object.keys(odba).forEach(function(key, value) {
  return odba[key] = false;
})

console.log(odba);
```

The above code results in:

```
{
  all: false,
  allA: false,
  allB: false,
  allC: false
}
```

however this is not correct since nested objects were ignored. I tried the following as well:

```
Object.keys(odba).forEach(function(key, value) {
        if(typeof key === 'object')
    {
            Object.keys(key).forEach(function(k, v){
        return odba[k] = false;
        })
    }
    return odba[key] = false;
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that you can recursively call on your nested object values to set their values to `false`. By checking if a value is an object, you can call the function again with the object value, for example:

```js
function allToFalse(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    const value = obj[key];
    if(Object(value) === value) // if value is an object
      allToFalse(value);
    else
      obj[key] = false;
  });
}

const odba = { "all": false, "allA": false, "allB": false, "allC": { "allD": false, "allE": { "allF": true }, } }
allToFalse(odba);
console.log(odba);
```

The above will modify your object in place (as your current code does). If you want to create a function that produces a new object and leaves the old one as is, then you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build a new object, again using recursion to build your nested objects also. For example:

```js
function allToFalse(obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) =>
    [key, Object(val) === val ? allToFalse(val) : false]
  ));
}

const odba = { "all": false, "allA": false, "allB": false, "allC": { "allD": false, "allE": { "allF": true }, } }
console.log(allToFalse(odba));
```

There's also a "hack" that you can do with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) and its reviver function. Firstly, you can stringify your object into a JSON string, and then parse it back into an object, where you use the reviver to specify `false` as the new value. `JSON.parse()` will handle the recursion for you, but this method isn't very efficient and can potentially make you lose some properties (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description)):

```js
function allToFalse(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, val) => typeof val === "boolean" ? false : val);
}

const odba = { "all": false, "allA": false, "allB": false, "allC": { "allD": false, "allE": { "allF": true }, } }
console.log(allToFalse(odba));
```